# PreferencesScreen crashes on click

Tags: android, android-intent, key, preferences

I have placed this into my PreferencesActivity

PreferencesActivity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences); 
    Preference preferences = findPreference("key"); 
    preferences.setIntent(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class));
}
```

preferences.xml

```
<PreferenceScreen
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Preferences">


<Preference android:key="Pssword" android:title="Set SMS Notification Password"></Preference>
</PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

The moment i try to enter the preferences screen it crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a NullPointException because your `key` preference doesn't exist.

Replace your line `Preference preferences = findPreference("key");` with `Preference preferences = findPreference("Pssword");`

This should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 3):

Your preference is called `Pssword`, not `key`.